# switch from one view to another

Tags: xcode4

I have a view controller with a tableview, I would make that any row of the press, always goes to the same view. I tried so:
cntrl + click on first cell the view, towards the other view. (storyboard segues - push) appeared as a new arrow happens but it don't make what i hope.
(I created a table view from an array)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
MyViewController *myViewControllerScreen = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myViewControllerScreen animated:YES];
[myViewControllerScreen release];
}
```

this will take you always to "MyViewController"

hope this is what you're looking for